# knockout dynamic expression value for class - css binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a knockout expression below:

```
<span class='icon' data-bind='css: step_type() '></span>
```

if my step_type() return register :

```
<!-- in case of  step_type() return a register -->
<span class='icon 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7' data-bind='css: step_type() '></span>


<!-- in case of step_type() return a date -->
<span class='icon 0 1 2 3' data-bind='css: step_type() '></span>
```

What I noticed from the output knockout does not take expression value correctly instead it takes indices of each character in the string value. below is what  I expected to see

```
<!-- in case of step_type() return: date -->
<span class='icon date' data-bind='css: step_type() '></span>

<!-- in case of step_type() return: register -->
<span class='icon register' data-bind='css: step_type() '></span>
```

Do I miss something ? Please help how to get this done.

Comment: try something like this `<span class='icon' data-bind='css: {"classname":step_type()=='register'} '></span>` . if there is a match css will apply

Comment: this might work but it will not serve my purpose since step_type() can return almost 100 different values and it will end up using big amount of conditions.

Comment: help me undersatnd bit more . do you need a `if` check on top of element ? i will post some sample answer we dicuss there

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation. I have edited it. could you please take a look.

Comment: check the edits in answer and let me know . cheers

Comment: Please show the code for `step_type` function. The problem is in there!!

Comment: added fiddle you can check code in that .

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from your question

You need to add a css to a element conditionally . so, we need to do something like this .

**Input :**

```
<span class='icon' data-bind='css:{"abc":true}'></span>
```

**OutPut :**

```
<span class='icon abc' data-bind='css:{"abc":true}'></span>
```

If you need a `if` check on top of element here we go

```
<!-- ko if : step_type()== 'your value' -->
<span class='icon' data-bind='css:{"abc":true}'></span>
<!--/ko-->
```

**Edit :**
Then you need to have computed of `step_type` like below

```
vm.step_type= ko.Computed(function() {
        return (check condition here) ? "register" : "date";
    }, vm);
```

later on in you binding do like

```
<span class='icon' data-bind='css:step_type'></span> **(i/p)**

<span class='icon register' data-bind='css:step_type'></span> **(o/p)**
```

You can refer the Docs [**here**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) neatly mentioned how to deal

Working fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/gcp4g2vz/1/)

Comment: this is the result I got : <span class='icon 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7' data-bind='css:step_type'></span> **(o/p)**

Comment: i added working fiddle which seems ok to me . possibly a fiddle with your issue is appreciated . cheers